# Angular migration guide

Tags: angular

While searching for how to use ES2020 with Angular, I stumbled upon the below link
https://angular.io/guide/migration-update-module-and-target-compiler-options

It starts by saying "This migration adjusts the target and module settings ...". Upon reading the whole document, I did not find what "this migration" meant. Is it referring to some command which needs to be run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did not understand what this meant I had to check with Angular team and found that this document was indeed obsolete. I deleted with the PR https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/46257